# What is the ?0 type in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types, wildcard

```
scala> Try(Class.forName("scala.util.Try"))
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res54: scala.util.Try[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 } = Success(class scala.util.Try)
```

Can someone please explain what is the `?0` type? When I try to use it in code, doesn't compile.

`val tryMongo: Try[Class[?0]] = Try(Class.forName(MONGO_COLLECTION_CLASS))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually appears for [existential type](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/), so try:

```
scala> val tryMongo: Try[Class[`?0`]] forSome { type `?0`} = Try(Class.forName("scala.util.Try"))
tryMongo: scala.util.Try[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 } = Success(class scala.util.Try)
```

Note that you can choose any name, like `T` or `A` instead of `?0` - it's just a convention for compiler messages (`?` was probably chosen because same sign used in Java). You can also use a shortcut `XXX[_]`, which is completely equivalent to `XXX[T] forSome { type T }`:

```
scala> val tryMongo: Try[Class[_]] = Try(Class.forName("scala.util.Try"))
tryMongo: scala.util.Try[Class[_]] = Success(class scala.util.Try)
```

Comment: What's the `forSome { type ?0}`? Anonymous type or something?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar here is some explanation: http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/